# Rule of zero article

Tags: grammaticality

I understand from [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-article-grammar-1692619) that:

> In general, no article is used with (i) **proper nouns**, (ii) **mass nouns where the reference is indefinite**, or (iii) **plural count nouns where the reference is
>   indefinite**. Also, no article is generally used (iv)**when referring to means of transport (by plane)** or (v) **common expressions of time and place (at
>   midnight, in jail)**.

However, I note the following sentence and note the lack of article before the noun (in italics):

> We are yet to obtain *German law review*.

German law review does not appear to fall into any of the above categories. So, have I missed any other category? Or is *German law review* not a noun?

This is in the context of getting a document reviewed from a German law perspective.

Comment: Where did you read the sentence?

Comment: What is _German law review_? Is it a publication, a process, etc?

Comment: Hey, in an email from a senior executive.

Comment: Is the senior executive a native English speaker?

Comment: Oh yeah I should’ve added that he’s a native English speaker

Comment: It's common (and as far as I know grammatical) to omit articles when referring to processes in the abstract ("this needs oversight/review/consultation") which could be seen as the case here (what you call mass nouns with indefinite reference). On the other hand, it's common in informal communication, such as emails, to omit articles and adopt a style sometimes called telegraphese. There's an expectation that people will know roughly what you're talking about so you can be brief.

Comment: @Stuart F Saying 'It's grammatical' is probably unhelpful. 'It is acceptable to relax the laws of formal grammar in (once upon a time, telegraphs,) headlines, Emails  etc provided clarity is not compromised.' But it often is. // Your guess that this could be a broadening (of 'review') into a non-count usage is possibly a good one. I'll check in some dictionaries.

Comment: ... I've only found examples of what they call non-count usages when complements of prepositions (under review, for review). I'd guess this is telegraphese rather than intended boundary-pushing.

Comment: Would we want 'the' German law review? If we waited for German law *approval*, that would be reasonable, right? Also, if emails used flawless language for interoffice commentary, those authors are spending way too much time on them.

Comment: @StuartF is it really a 'mass noun' though? This dictionary [https://www.google.com/search?q=review+define&oq=review+define&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.2179j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8] categorises it as a noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth if it's telegraphic, then is it grammatical to add an article so it reads: "We are yet to obtain **a** German law review."?

Comment: I think you mean "... does it become grammatical ..." and I'd say (a) telegraphese and standard English have different rules, so I'm not keen on 'become grammatical' (which implies the telegraphese was in some way unacceptable). But (b) I don't know the exact nature of the string 'German law review', but certainly 'we are yet to receive the regular quarterly review' and 'we are yet to receive an official Agency review', where there is no compound structure,  would be ungrammatical in standard English without the artciles.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth just to make sure I understand it correctly, we need an article "an" before "official Agency review" because in that case "review" is a noun?

Comment: Compare 'He is a Scottish football manager', where the head noun of the phrase 'Scottish football manager' is 'manager', a common noun, which requires the indefinite article before the whole phrase. 'He is a manager' ==> 'He is a well respected, gritty, no-nonsense Scottish football manager' . The only possible complications with your example are (1) is 'review' the count usage (contrast 'This is an expensive new football' with 'I love football') and (2) is the string compound, which could alter countness  (as with 'He used to sell real estate' but 'She has an estate in North Wales').

Comment: Quality of comments is good and may yet lead to an answer that is not merely opinion. Leave open.

Answer (score 2):

It's condensed language - I feel it is broadly correct - he is saying "we are yet to obtain review for compliance with German law".  Both sound a bit clumsy - the latter would be intelligible to an outsider, whilst what your executive wrote would be intelligible only to those who knew the context.  Here "review" (rather than "a ... review" or "the ... review") could be one response or more than one response, I would say it is a category of response rather than saying whether you are getting one response or more than one.

Answer (score 0):

"Obtain review" is a phrase found in several legal documents including statutes. Hence it must be considered an acceptable element in legal writing. The zero-article form of review has obvious analogs in other uses of the verb "obtain" and expressions such as "pass review", "submit for review", etc.

We can look at other usages outside the legal sphere. "We are yet to obtain approval" or "We are yet to obtain permission" are grammatical - Merriam-Webster has "The government has so far withheld approval of the drug." ([Approval - examples](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approval#examples)) In this context, "approval" and "permission" are non-count nouns. (In other contexts, "approval" can be a count noun meaning an act of approval.)

The example "We are yet to obtain German law review" is structured the same way, and intended to have the same or similar meaning - passing a stage in the path for a document to be fully approved and ready for use.

Review is often used in a non-count way with a zero article: "The document is in review", "Submit it for review", "The document has passed review", etc. (The same can be done with "inspection" and many other nouns denoting an abstract state e.g. "in motion", "under protest", "with regret".)

It is also reasonable to put an adjective or noun as a modifier before review: "the document has passed internal review". One example from [Science Daily](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2095263516300474) is "The scheme must be approved in the shareholders' meeting and pass government review".

The remaining question is whether "obtain review" can function the same way as "pass review". A Google search shows that this is a legal expression found in various statutes, although it is not widely used outside the legal environment:

> The United States Code says "All final determinations, findings, and conclusions of the Attorney General under this subchapter shall be final and conclusive decisions of the matters involved, except that any person aggrieved by a final decision of the Attorney General may obtain review of the decision in the United States Court of Appeals for the District of Columbia or for the circuit in which his principal place of business is located upon petition filed with the court and delivered to the Attorney General within thirty days after notice of the decision." [21 USC 877](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title21-section877&num=0&edition=prelim): Judicial review, September 29, 2022

> "An appellee may obtain review of a judgment or order entered in the same action which may adversely affect him by filing a notice of review and section B of the docketing statement required by subdivision 15-26A-4(2) with the clerk of the Supreme Court within twenty days after the service of the notice of appeal." South Dakota Codified Laws § 15-26A-22 ([ref](https://casetext.com/statute/south-dakota-codified-laws/title-15-civil-procedure/chapter-26a-rules-of-civil-appellate-procedure/section-15-26a-22-appellees-right-to-obtain-review))

> There is a heading "Who may obtain review" in the Oregon Revised Statutes, Volume 1, Title 3, Chapter 34, Section 34.020. ([ref](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_34.020))

Answer (score -1):

"German law review" is either the title of a publication (in which case, it should be capitalized) or it is an error. Review needs an article.

Comment: Thanks! I’ve added clarification, would you answer stand?